# Night Light settings not persistent

Tags: gnome, 17.10

Night Light in Ubuntu 17.10 on my laptop looses it's settings after reboot/wake-up from standby. E.g. when I configure it to manual, the times are back to 00:00.

Is anyone experiencing the same problem or has even a solution to the issue?

Comment: I am having the same issue. I upgraded from 17.04.

Comment: @IrmakCakmak I did a clean installation from thumb drive. So this seems to be independent of the installation path.

Comment: I have the same issue on Fedora 27. So I believe it is a GNOME issue.

Answer (score 2):

In your browser open 'Gnome Shell Extensions'.
Select 'Installed extensions' and open 'Night Light Slider' configuration.
Turn off 'Enable always'.

Comment: As you are new to AskUbuntu there is one suggestion: It's much more easy to understand with a screenshot.

Comment: Thanks mike, I will try this once I'm back at this machine and will let you know about my results

Comment: Given that @Manu3l0us never reported back with his results, I will give my report: this did seem to work for me. While the OP never stated that he actually had the "Night Light Slider" extension installed, I did have that extension installed on my machine which was experiencing the same problem described by the OP. Adjusting the _Enable Always_ setting (as this answer recommends) has fixed the problem.