# Something keeps enabling Gnome Night Light

Tags: 18.04, gnome, night-light

This is driving me nuts. Some time ago I installed redshift and xflux but since they didn't work I uninstalled them.

Since then my Night Light keeps enabling itself every now and then after disabling it. It is driving me crazy.

How do I figure out where's the culprit?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the "Night Light Slider" extension it could be similar to this problem:

- [Night Light settings not persistent](https://askubuntu.com/questions/975816/night-light-settings-not-persistent)

The answer posted there states:

> In your browser open 'Gnome Shell Extensions'. Select 'Installed
>   extensions' and open 'Night Light Slider' configuration. Turn off
>   'Enable always'.